# upgrade from 14.04 LTS to 16.04.1 LTS still fails

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

Now that upgrades from 14.04 LTS are enabled, the upgrade still fails for the following repos:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://172.22.152.125/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W:Failed to fetch http://172.22.152.125/ubuntu/dists/xenial/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found
...
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Are there other locations we can use? Or will the script get updated?

Comment: That looks like a private IP, which is weird, since Ubuntu repositories are not on your LAN (I assume). Have you done anything funky with your hosts file or other network settings?

Comment: The location you're using must be out of date, follow what I just linked to change your mirror to another one with the updates.

Comment: I was able to upgrade after changing servers and removing some company IP's listed in my sources.list file.

Happily running 16.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 0):

I was able to upgrade after changing servers and removing some company IP's listed in my sources.list file. Happily running 16.04.1 LTS